# How to find MainActivity in as3 air mobile

Tags: android, actionscript-3, android-facebook, facebook-as3-api

I want to create android app by using air mobile as3.

My app can log in facebook. And I use [com.freshplanet](https://github.com/freshplanet/ANE-Facebook) and my `application.xml`

look like following:

```
<android>
<manifestAdditions><![CDATA[<manifest android:installLocation="auto" >
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.LoginActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>
    <activity android:name="com.freshplanet.ane.AirFacebook.DialogActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"></activity>

</application>
</manifest>]]></manifestAdditions>
```

Moreover, in facebook app, I have to add `ClassName` to log in facebook.

The question is how can I find Main Activity in air mobile as3?

I try `Main`, but I got error when log in facebook.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I follow? You will probably need to use an ANE to get access to the Main Activity but what do you need it for?

Comment: I need the locate of main activity because facebook app setting is required this one to log in facebook.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Your main activity is called ".AppEntry"

Long answer: One way to find out all the details of the APK AIR builds for you is to just take a look at the manifest inside. apktool does a good job of extracting the contents of APKs into something you can easily read: [apktool homepage](http://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/)